# Cannot run xampp php on localhost to test html email form

Tags: php, html, forms, apache, xampp

I am using xampp (apache) php  and want to test my html email form locally. When I use this `action` in the `form` tag it works (I get a "thanks for contacting us" confirmation):

`<form id="contactus" action="http://www.html-form-guide.com//files/contact-form/simple-form-1-1/contactform.php" novalidate method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" >`

*Note: This url used in* `action` *was obtained from an a website that guides email form design.*

But I cannot code `action` correctly to get it to run using my local .php file. I've tried all of these (based on suggestions in stackoverflow posts), none have worked:

1. `action="contactform.php"`
2. `action="http://localhost/contactform.php"`
3. `action="<?php echo site_url('contactform'); ?>"`

I have my .php and .html email files in the same folder. The directory path is: **c:\xampp\htdocs\contactform.php** & **c:\xampp\htdocs\Contact us.html**

The way I am testing is using Cntrl+O to open the Contact us.html in Chrome. I can see the email form. When I input name, email address and a dummy message it works when I use `action="http://www.html-form-guide.com//files/contact-form/simple-form-1-1/contactform.php"` but not with 1, 2 and 3 above. Thank you for any help.

Lastly, I have no problem opening the .php file using localhost/contactform.php.

Update: If this helps here's a script from my XAMP Control Panel:

    `22::37:25  [main]   Initializing Control Panel
    22::37:25  [main]   Windows Version: Windows 8  64-bit
    22::37:25  [main]   XAMPP Version: 5.6.8
    22::37:25  [main]   Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
    22::37:25  [main]   You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
    22::37:25  [main]   most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
    22::37:25  [main]   there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
    22::37:25  [main]   about running this application with administrator rights!
    22::37:25  [main]   XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
    22::37:25  [main]   Checking for prerequisites
    22::37:25  [main]   All prerequisites found
    22::37:25  [main]   Initializing Modules
    22::37:25  [Apache]     Initializing module...
    22::37:25  [Apache]     Checking for module existence...
    22::37:25  [Apache]     Checking for required tools...
    22::37:25  [Apache]     Checking for service (name="Apache2.4"): Service not installed
    22::37:25  [Apache]     Service Path: Service Not Installed
    22::37:25  [Apache]     Checking default ports...
    22::37:25  [mysql]  Initializing module...
    22::37:25  [mysql]  Checking for module existence...
    22::37:25  [mysql]  Checking for required tools...
    22::37:25  [mysql]  Checking for service (name="mysql"): Service not installed
    22::37:25  [mysql]  Service Path: Service Not Installed
    22::37:25  [mysql]  Checking default ports...
    22::37:25  [filezilla]  Initializing module...
    22::37:25  [filezilla]  Checking for module existence...
    22::37:25  [filezilla]  Checking for required tools...
    22::37:25  [filezilla]  Checking for service (name="FileZillaServer"): Service not installed
    22::37:25  [filezilla]  Service Path: Service Not Installed
    22::37:25  [filezilla]  Checking default ports...
    22::37:25  [mercury]    Initializing module...
    22::37:25  [mercury]    Checking for module existence...
    22::37:25  [mercury]    Checking for required tools...
    22::37:25  [mercury]    Checking default ports...
    22::37:25  [Tomcat]     Initializing module...
    22::37:25  [Tomcat]     Checking for module existence...
    22::37:25  [Tomcat]     Checking for required tools...
    22::37:25  [Tomcat]     Checking for service (name="Tomcat7"): Service not installed
    22::37:25  [Tomcat]     Service Path: Service Not Installed
    22::37:25  [Tomcat]     Checking default ports...
    22::37:25  [main]   Enabling autostart for module "Apache"
    22::37:25  [main]   Enabling autostart for module "MySQL"
    22::37:25  [main]   Starting Check-Timer
    22::37:25  [main]   Control Panel Ready
    22::37:26  [Apache]     Autostart active: starting...
    22::37:26  [Apache]     Checking default ports...
    22::37:26  [Apache]     Attempting to start Apache app...
    22::37:26  [Apache]     Executing "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"
    22::37:26  [Apache]     Return code: 0
    22::37:26  [mysql]  Autostart active: starting...
    22::37:26  [mysql]  Checking default ports...
    22::37:26  [mysql]  Attempting to start MySQL app...
    22::37:26  [mysql]  Executing ""c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini" --standalone"
    22::37:26  [mysql]  Return code: 0
    22::37:26  [Apache]     Status change detected: running
    22::37:26  [mysql]  Status change detected: running`

Comment: the first option should work

Comment: pay attention to that 'zzz' folder...

Comment: If you are opening the .html file directly using chrome, it wont work. Start the server. and go to the localhost/contactus.html

Answer (score 1):

1. is your server launched?
2. are you accessing your page using http://localhost?
3. can you access directly to your php file via the browser?
4. if you are using linux, do your apache user have read and execute access right on those file?

Comment: To answer your questions: 1) my XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.1 shows modules Apache and MySQL running; 2) by "page" do you mean "Contact us.html"? If so, yes; 3) Yes. From the browser I enter "localhost/zzz/contactform.php" in the url window; 4) Windows 8.

Comment: Also, based on the suggestion of Mathivanan I have entered this in the url window: localhost/zzz/Contact us.html. When I complete the email form and submit I now see the .php version of the email form, which also has a submit button. I hit submit again but nothing happens, except I see "waiting for localhost . . . " onscreen.

Comment: I am seeing this in  the XAMPP Control Panel: "You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for most application stuff but whenever you do something with services there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think about running this application with administrator rights!" Is this hurting the use of my email form & php? If yes how do I acquire administrator rights?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem but just right click on the icon of xampp before starting it and click on "as an administrator". and then try again your issue. as i understand what u said your form use ajax request, launch your browser console and go on the network tab and check the state of the requests sent. i using chrome or mozilla you should be able to see the returned message from your server by click on the request and navigate between tabs. just try it and tell me what happens

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't fully understand. I did this: Chrome/More tools/Javascript Console and saw this: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK) https://www.google.com/uds/?file=ads&v=3&packages=search&async=2" I don't understand your comment "click on the request and navigate between tabs."

Comment: "now check if the request your file is sending is correct. " How do I do this?

Comment: i mean, 404 means your browser CANT access your file(i did an error). i think you should read about the devtools of chrome first https://developer.chrome.com/devtools